# is an expression in a for loop executed every time?

Tags: python, c, for-loop

Let `l` be a list. In this python script, is the function `len(l)` executed every time in the for loop?

```python
for i in range(len(l)):
    #do something here
```

If so, it would be very wasteful when `len(l)` is large. We should introduce `a=len(l)` and then use `range(a)` in the `for` loop so that `len` function is only used once.

What about the following case?

```python
for i in range(3+4):
    #do something here
```

Is `3+4` computed every time or just once?

What about the for loop in C such as the following?

```c
for (i = 1; i < 3+4; i++) {
    do something here;
}
```

Comment: If the compiler can prove that no other side-effect can change the result of the expression, it does not need to be evaluated every time.

Comment: For your python example, `len(l)` is only evaluated once and `range()` returns a `range` object. Even if it wouldn't be, `len(some_list)` is `O(1)`.

Comment: If it were evaluated every time, how could the loop work? Each time it's evaluated it would return a new range that starts at 0, and you would never go through all the numbers.

Comment: Just to add that `for i in range(len(some_list)):` is anti-pattern in python anyway

Comment: No, that wouldn't make any sense. The expression should evaluate to *some iterable*, and then that iterable is iterated over. It doesn't make any sense for it to work any other way

Comment: But note, even if what you were saying were true, somehow, that doesn't mean that "t would be very wasteful when len(l) is large." It wouldn't be wasteful, `len(l)` is a constant-time operation (it merely *retreives* the length of the list)

Comment: The key thing to understand is the difference between an iterator-based for-loop (sometimes called a "for-each" loop) with a classic, C-style for loop (which is basically just sugar for a while loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, the for argument `range(len(l))` is evaluated once and produces a `range` object that acts like a generator when it is requested for each iteration of the loop until it reaches the end of the sequence. Thus `len(l)` is only evaluated once. Note that depending on what you do in the loop body, a simpler `for i in l:` might be more appropriate.

In the C expression `for (i = 1; i < 3+4; i++)`, the test clause `i < 3+4` is evaluated before each iteration of the loop and since `3+4` is a constant expression, the compiler evaluates it at compile time and just generates code to compare `i` with `7` before the iteration of the loop.

Note however that if the loop is small, the compiler might expand it into a sequence of operations and remove the tests and increment completely.

Comment: "and produces a generator" it does not, it produces a `range` object, which is not a generator, it isn't even an iterator, it is an iterable sequence type. So, for example, try `next(range(10))` But that is a nitpick, upvoted anyway